# Two Player guessing game python

Tags: python

So my professor told me to make a number guessing game. I did that but she later uploads guidelines on how she want's it done. My code is so different and I don't know how to edit it to match her expectation. Please help.

Player One picks a number and Player Two has 5 Guesses to guess it. If he manages to do so, he wins, if not, he losses and Player One wins.

If for example Player one picks the number '3' and Player Two enters the number '3' on any of his goes, it still says Player One wins.

This is my code and my attached assignment photo

```py
def Game():
    Guess = 0
    NumberOfGuesses = 0
    NumberToGuess = int(input("Player One enter you chosen number: "))
    while NumberToGuess < 1 or NumberToGuess > 10:
        NumberToGuess = int(input("Not a valid choice, please enter another number: "))
    while Guess != NumberToGuess and NumberOfGuesses < 5:
        Guess = int(input("Player Two have a guess: "))
        NumberOfGuesses = NumberOfGuesses + 1
    if Guess == NumberToGuess:
        print("Player Two wins.")
    else:
        print("Player One wins.")

Game()
```

[my assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8xKZ.png)

Comment: Can I suggest that you start by reading the instructions from your "professor"?

Comment: I think with couple more examples you would clarify better the game dynamic. I thinkf It is still unclear for the reader.

Comment: Hey, I tried the Game and it works for me!!

Answer (score 0):

So the assignment is pretty clear in my opinion.
This is a turn-based PvP Game with guessing a **random** number.
Your main_game loop needs the parameters on how many rounds are played.
Every round consists of 2 game_steps, which include 2 tries to guess the number + some I/O Stuff that is described in your assignment. Guessing on the first try rewards 5 points, and guessing on the second try rewards 3 points.

Personally, I refrain from using while loops unless for very specific use cases. In my opinion, for loops are just better. You can iterate over lists, ranges, dataframes, etc., and easily unpack data while you are at it.

The next thing I would recommend is to stick to the [PEP-8 pythonic naming convention](https://realpython.com/python-pep8/#naming-conventions). It just makes it easier to read the code. Whenever I see a capital letter in a python script, I instantly think of a class. And later in the workplace, it is extremely important that code is easily readable.

If I were you, I would discard your code and start from scratch, I don't think there is much to salvage from the code you provided. Just read your assignment carefully and think about how you would solve it logically before starting to code.